# Is there a way to join a Windows 10 computer to Azure AD using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, windows-10

I want to join computers in my organization to Azure AD using a PowerShell script.

I tried using the `New-AzureADDevice` command

But in the example:

```
New-AzureADDevice -AccountEnabled $true -DisplayName "My new device" -AlternativeSecurityIds $altsecid -DeviceId $guid -DeviceOSType "OS/2" -DeviceOSVersion "9.3"
```

can someone explain where parameter `AlternativeSecurityIds` comes from?

Comment: have a look at this: https://jairocadena.com/2016/02/01/azure-ad-join-what-happens-behind-the-scenes/ quote from this blog post "AlternativeSecurityIds contains the certificate thumbprint with a specific scheme format (i.e. “X509:<SHA1-TP-PUBKEY>:” + thumbprint). This is how Azure AD will find the device object when the device presents the certificate upon authentication."

Comment: I think it is the 'key' you provided in Create device.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-post-devices?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example

Answer (score 1):

AlternativeSecurityId which consists of three elements whereby only two would be needed for devices.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/alternativesecurityid?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
AlternativeSecurityIds        : {class AlternativeSecurityId {
                                  IdentityProvider:
                                  Key: System.Byte[]
                                  Type: 2
                                }
                                }
```

- Key itself is of type described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dvre/1f2ebba7-7783-42c4-982a-ce9ca76af949)

  **X509:[thumbprint]+[publickeyhash]**
- Type determines the purpose of the key (eg Bitlocker, Windows Hello,Recoverykeys)

  ```
       $key = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("X509:<SHA1-TP-PUBKEY><Thumbprint>")
       $altsecids = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{

       #'IdentityProvider' = 'null'
       'Key' = $key
       'Type' = "2" }




       New-AzureADDevice -AccountEnabled $true -DisplayName '<NAME>' -DeviceOSType 'OS/2' -DeviceOSVersion '9.3' -AlternativeSecurityIds $altsecids -DeviceId (New-Guid)
  ```

This is mostly used for internal use and my understanding you will not able to achieve your requirement.

[image]

Currently, there is no powershell script/commandlet  that can auto join with AAD

There is already an existing [Uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20399941-all-powershell-bash-script-azure-ad-join)  for the same.

The other option would be able to make use of :

- [Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/enroll-a-windows-10-device-automatically-using-group-policy) , [OOBE](https://petri.com/join-windows-10-to-azure-active-directory-during-oobe), [bulk enrollment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/windows-bulk-enroll#:%7E:text=Select%20Enroll%20in%20Azure%20AD,Bulk%20Token%20is%20fetched%20successfully.) and [Autopilot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/autopilot/windows-autopilot)